# How do I do sum of first k elements of a row of a Pascal's Triangle efficiently?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

More specifically, I want to:

$^nC_0 + ^nC_1 + ^nC_2 + ..... + ^nC_k$

I tried doing it linearly by calculating $^nC_{j+1}$ by multiplying $^nC_{j}$ with (n-j+1)/j.

The answer it gives is correct for small numbers. Since n and k can be large, I need have keep modding with P, a given prime number.

My method fails since I have to divide with j, which breaks the mod.
Any suggestions?

Comment: To save anyone else the effort, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Partial_sums) says there's no closed formula for the requested sum.

Comment: So you want to compute the sum modulo P? If dividing by j is the problem, you can find the [inverse of j mod P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is fine.  You just need to know how to do modular division.  Modular division is a bit different from division of two integers.  You can do modular division, say $x/y \bmod p$, by computing computing the modular inverse of $y$, $y^{-1}\bmod p$, and then multiplying that by $x$.  You can compute the modular inverse using the extended Euclidean algorithm.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse.

A slight correction:

$${n \choose j+1} = {n \choose j} \times {(n-j) \over j+1}.$$

You had an off-by-one error in the formula.  To do this modulo $p$, replace dvision by $j+1$ with multiplication by the modular inverse of $j+1$ modulo $p$.

Comment: so instead of $(^nC_j * (n-j+1) / j) \bmod p$  , I should $(^nC_j * (n-j+1) * ModInv(j,p)) \bmod p$. Do i understand this correctly? Will this work with smaller numbers as well?

Comment: @RishavBanka, basically, yes... but see edited answer for a slight correction to your formula.

Comment: Oh, yeah. You are right. I was thinking programmatically where $j$ had already been incremented. I mixed up my math and the code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

One interesting fact about Pascal's triangle is that each rows' numbers are a power of 11. For instance, the first row is 11 to the power of 0 (1), the second is eleven to the power of 1 (1,1), the third is 11 to the power of 2 (1,2,1), etc. This identity can help your algorithm because any row at index n will have the numbers of 11^n. Then, using something like a "to_string" conversion in C++ or the "read" function in Haskell, you can select the amount of numbers you would like to sum over in your string of numbers, convert them back to an integer, and then sum over them.
Here is some pseudo-code to help illustrate my answer:

```
    int n = 7
    int k = 5
    int full_row = pow(11,n)
    string str_full_row = to_string(full_row)
    int sum=0
    int index=0
    for string i in str_full_row:
        index+=1
        sum+=(string_to_int(i))
        if index==k:
            break
```

In this case, the answer is the "sum" variable, and you don't need to use the nCr trick above. The "n" variable is the row, the "k" variable is the amount of terms within the row that you want to sum over (and it starts at 0), and the "index" simply keeps track of the the number of iterations that have happened within the for loop.
I hope this helps!

EDIT: Having reviewed the answers below, I see that there is an obvious mistake for rows in which the numbers within the row are double-digit or beyond. I do not know how to correct this.

Comment: I don't think  this works. For example, the third row is 1,3,3,1 But I don't see anything in your pseudocode that tells you whether $11^3=1331$ should be decoded as 1,3,3,1 or 1,33,1 or something else.

Comment: Initially I misunderstood the question and proposed very same thing (now deleted). To make it actually work you need to work on array and split the number from both sides, decoding values, estimating number of digits and help yourself with $2^i$ as the sum of the full row. Although it is indeed interesting fact, there are downsides - you have to provide estimate and after overflows spreads among multiple consecutive digits, it becomes highly inefficient and hard to handle. The given method is very fast, and since there is no closed formula *probably* we cannot get faster.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't explain how to interpret the string representation of $11^n$ as the $n$th row of the triangle. OK, so for the first four rows, you know that all the entries are single digits. But what about after then? How are you doing to split the 100th row, for example?

Comment: And the handy insight to get given number is to calculate polygonal number - which is effectively the same as calculating from Newton symbol. Also the representation integer -> string and back is heavier than several basic arithmetic operations. So this is for sure not way to go.

Comment: Also it seems that you have created two accounts, is it right?

Comment: Since you do not know how to correct your answer, well it does not answer the question.